# put several plots from list of results into single figure

Tags: r, plot

I'm doing several matching analyses using MatchIt, and in hopes of being efficient with my coding I use map to loop over different model inputs, such as different sets of covariates. I end up with a list of matchit objects that I loop over to extract findings and diagnostic output. I'd like to create a figure that combines the plots for each model into a single figure.

The principal seems fairly straightforward when I'm not using a matchit object. For example, the below code outputs a single figure with histograms for Sepal.Width and Sepal.Length from the iris data set:

```
library(tidyverse) 

plots <- iris %>% select(contains("Sepal")) %>% map(hist)
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plots %>% map(plot)
```

But when I try to use this same approach with the MatchIt objects, as in the below, I get a figure with one plot crammed in the top of the plot area and no other figures.

Why are the results different for the MatchIt output, and how can I combine the matchit plots into one plot?

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(MatchIt)
data("lalonde")

formula1=treat ~ age + educ + race + married + 
  nodegree + re74 + re75
formula2=treat ~ age + educ + race + married + 
  nodegree + re74 + re75
formulas=list(formula1,formula2)

results <- formulas %>% map(~matchit(formula=.x, data=lalonde, method=NULL, distance="glm"))

opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)

# set 2 x 1 layout
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
results %>% map(summary) %>% map(plot)
par(opar)
```

Comment: According to the help text for the function plot.summary.matchit, it is set to generate a love plot of standardized mean differences.

Comment: Try using results %>% map(plot) with the type argument to get a variety of plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatchIt:::plot.summary.matchit` internally messes around with the `par`s, that's why it is not working, but we can hack it.

```
plot_summary_matchit <- function (x, abs = TRUE, var.order = "data", threshold = c(0.1, 
                                                                                   0.05), position = "bottomright", ...) {
  # .pardefault <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)  ## deleted
  # on.exit(par(.pardefault))  ## deleted
  sub <- inherits(x, "summary.matchit.subclass")
  matched <- sub || !is.null(x[["sum.matched"]])
  un <- !is.null(x[["sum.all"]])
  standard.sum <- if (un) 
    x[["sum.all"]]
  else x[[if (sub) 
    "sum.across"
    else "sum.matched"]]
  if (!"Std. Mean Diff." %in% colnames(standard.sum)) {
    stop("Not appropriate for unstandardized summary.  Run summary() with the standardize = TRUE option, and then plot.", 
         call. = FALSE)
  }
  if (un) {
    sd.all <- x[["sum.all"]][, "Std. Mean Diff."]
  }
  if (matched) {
    sd.matched <- x[[if (sub) 
      "sum.across"
      else "sum.matched"]][, "Std. Mean Diff."]
  }
  var.names <- rownames(standard.sum)
  var.order <- MatchIt:::match_arg(var.order, c("data", "matched", "unmatched", 
                                                "alphabetical"))
  if (!un && var.order == "unmatched") 
    stop("'var.order' cannot be \"unmatched\" if un = TRUE in the call to summary().", 
         call. = FALSE)
  if (!matched && var.order == "matched") 
    stop("'var.order' cannot be \"matched\" if method = NULL in the original call to matchit().", 
         call. = FALSE)
  if (abs) {
    if (un) 
      sd.all <- abs(sd.all)
    if (matched) 
      sd.matched <- abs(sd.matched)
    xlab <- "Absolute Standardized\nMean Difference"
  }
  else {
    xlab <- "Standardized Mean Difference"
  }
  ord <- switch(var.order, data = rev(seq_along(var.names)), 
                matched = order(sd.matched), unmatched = order(sd.all), 
                alphabetical = order(var.names, decreasing = TRUE))
  dotchart(if (un) 
    sd.all[ord]
    else sd.matched[ord], labels = var.names[ord], xlab = xlab, 
    bg = NA, color = NA, ...)
  abline(v = 0)
  if (sub && length(x$sum.subclass) > 0) {
    for (i in seq_along(x$sum.subclass)) {
      sd.sub <- x$sum.subclass[[i]][, "Std. Mean Diff."]
      if (abs) 
        sd.sub <- abs(sd.sub)
      points(x = sd.sub[ord], y = seq_along(sd.sub), pch = as.character(i), 
             col = "gray60", cex = 0.6)
    }
  }
  if (un) {
    points(x = sd.all[ord], y = seq_along(sd.all), pch = 21, 
           bg = "white", col = "black")
  }
  if (matched) {
    points(x = sd.matched[ord], y = seq_along(sd.matched), 
           pch = 21, bg = "black", col = "black")
  }
  if (!is.null(threshold)) {
    if (abs) {
      abline(v = threshold, lty = seq_along(threshold))
    }
    else {
      abline(v = threshold, lty = seq_along(threshold))
      abline(v = -threshold, lty = seq_along(threshold))
    }
  }
  if (sum(matched, un) > 1 && !is.null(position)) {
    position <- match_arg(position, c("bottomright", "bottom", 
                                      "bottomleft", "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", 
                                      "right", "center"))
    legend(position, legend = c("All", "Matched"), pt.bg = c("white", 
                                                                    "black"), pch = 21, inset = 0.015, xpd = TRUE)
  }
  invisible(x)
}
```

### Usage

```
data("lalonde", package='MatchIt')
formulas <- replicate(2, treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75)
results <- lapply(formulas, \(x) MatchIt::matchit(formula=x, data=lalonde, method=NULL, distance="glm"))
opar <- par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
results |> lapply(summary) |> lapply(plot_summary_matchit)
par(opar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer of MatchIt also suggested the following solution:

> These are inherent limitations in R's plotting functionality. Use
> cobalt instead, which creates highly customizable plots using ggplot2
> and is compatible with matchit objects. love.plot() creates a very
> similar plot to plot(summary(.)).
>
> You might be able to do something like:

[Source](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/143#issuecomment-1426878465)

```
 library(patchwork) do.call(wrap_plots, c(lapply(results, love.plot),
 list(nrow = 2)))
```

Comment: You should include the source of your citation.

Comment: source has been added